# Bootstrap Equal Column

Tags: javascript, html

We were told to use this to get a question answered.

The following is a breakdown of our Menu; we apologize for the shape of the CSS/HTML/JS but were unaware as to how present it otherwise.

We're attempting to have all column/rows on the same height.
We're aware of row-eq-height but are apparently doing it wrong.

The code is as below:

Full Clip:
https://pastebin.com/Kc9KTkZU

Exerp:

```
<div class="row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content faq-cat-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active in fade" id="faq-cat-1">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-cat-1">
              <div class="panel panel-default panel-faq">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a data-parent="#accordion-cat-1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#faq-cat-1-sub-1">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">Sharable Appetizers <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></span>
                  <span><img src="images/menu-top-a.png" style="width:100%;"></span></h4></a>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="faq-cat-1-sub-1">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row-eq-height form-group">
```

Answer (score 1):

`.row-eq-height` is not a native class in Bootstrap. You'll need to add and define it yourself in the CSS:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

Please note: This class uses CSS3's flexbox layout mode, which is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and below. For more info, see [Bootstrap's info](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/).

Answer (score 0):

to make sur that all the child element will have the same hight use `flex` in the parent container , in your case added this to your css

```
.row-eq-height{
display:flex;
}
```